# How to search the contents of the current page by pre-selected text in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, search

Is there any configuration to fill in automatically a selected text to the in-page search textbox.

What I want Firefox to behave:

- Select a text in the current displayed page (normally by mouse)
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- The selected text is filled automatically in the search textbox
- Then we could eventually press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> to find next, etc.

This feature is currently used in PHPStorm IDE and I found it increased my work performance much.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are asking for – and exactly what you are asking for – has been present in Firefox since version 3.0:

- "[Firefox 3 Release Notes](http://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-US/firefox/3.0/releasenotes/)". *website-archive.mozilla.org*. Mozilla Foundation. "Find toolbar: the Find toolbar now opens with the current selection."

Indeed, you have explained the procedure with high accuracy. Right now, I am using Firefox and observing the presence of this feature with my own eyes.

**If your version of Firefox is not doing this, then I suggest you reset your configuration to default to get the functionality back.**

P.S. A special thanks to @Burgi for finding the link.

Comment: After resetting all settings and removing all add-ons, it didn't work on macOS. I'm currently running on macOS 10.12 and Firefox 52. BTW, everything seems to work well with Firefox 52 on Windows 10.

Comment: I had to open `about:config` and change the setting `accessibility.typeaheadfind.prefillwithselection` to `true` to make this work.  It appears bold which implies this is not the default setting.  I'm using FireFox Developer Edition 116